# How to use ExpressJS modules when in a subfile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I have a routing file which is exported and then required in the parent file. Let's say that I want to use an Express middleware such as cookieParser, but I want to use it within the child routing file. How do I do this, considering I do not have access to the express application in the child application? I cannot say `app.use(cookieParser)` in the child file because app is declared int he parent file

Answer (score 1):

You can [bind middleware to a router](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) just as you can to the main application.

```
router.use(cookieParser);
```